# How do I stop contents from overflowing their containers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overflow

I've found that the contact section of the following site keeps spilling over at the bottom, especially when the window width is reduced to mobile size:

http://phixhut.com/test/1page/onepage.html#contact

The CSS I have for the overlay section is:

```
-webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
transition: all 500ms ease;
padding: 55px 0 15px 0;
width: 100%;
background-color: #83aa30;
background-color: rgba(131, 170, 48, 0.6);
background-image: url("../images/GPlay.svg");
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
top: 0px;
```

The spill at the bottom disappears if I remove the "top: 0px" but then it appears to spill over at the top.

Not sure how to go about getting the contact section to resize pefectly to stop these spills. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems you are looking for overflow: hidden

Comment: Or overflow:auto; if you want the div to become scrollable, also height should be set.

Answer (score 0):

The solution, albeit inefficient, would be `overflow: hidden`

You shouldn't use that, however, because the majority of the time the use of that is to basically hide unwanted code. Rather, try to fix the issue in CSS without using the overflow: hidden, so that when you resize nothing overflows.

You could do that by making sure certain items aren't set to a fixed width or height, because if a screen resolution is smaller than that, it will overflow.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a few thing's causing your problem but the easiest way to sort it would be to remove the current `height` you have for `class="contact"` and set it to the `height` of your `overlay` container.

Personally I would re write your code.

It would make more sense to have your map and overlay as one background image and remove your absolute positioning and the extra div's you have in there.

It would A. Streamline your code and B. Reduce the amount of HTTP request's & C. your site would act in the fluid nature you are after.